# PL/SQL onChange event for apex plugin

Tags: plugins, radio-button, onchange, apex

I am working on a plugin for Apex 4.2, written in pl/sql. I am trying to hide/show specific features in my toolbar based on the selection of a radio button. I am already able to handle the hiding / showing of the toolbars. My problem is getting this to happen everytime I select a specific radio button. My code is below

```
$("#P13_GROUP").on("change", function () {
     if ( $("#P13_GROUP").val("UPDATE") ) { 
       $("#draw_point").hide();
       $("#longitude_minutes").hide();
       $("#longitude_seconds").hide();

    } else if ( $("#P13_GROUP").val("CREATE") ) {
       $("#draw_point").show();
       $("#longitude_minutes").show(); 
       $("#longitude_seconds").show();
   } else if ( $("#P13_GROUP").val("DISCARD") ) {
       $("#draw_point").show();
       $("#longitude_minutes").show(); 
       $("#longitude_seconds").show();

  }
```

})

Where P13_GROUP is a page item in Apex which represents the radio group. Radio group consists of three possible values / choices. All this is doing for me is hiding my fields. It hides my fields no matter what radio button I click. So if I clicked the radio button under 'DISCARD', my fields get hidden, when they should still show. If I click a different radio button after that, there is no change.

Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with a switch statement:

```
$("#P13_GROUP").on("change", function() {
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case "UPDATE": 
      $("#draw_point, #longitude_minutes, #longitude_seconds").hide();
      break;
    default:
      $("#draw_point, #longitude_minutes, #longitude_seconds").show();
      break;
  }
});
```